# 0 If I need to grab only the parent_id field from product.category to product.template model form view, what I should do?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo

`category_id=fields.Many2one('product.category',string='Category')`

by this I can easily inherit Categories( of course along with Parent) into product.template model.

But for some reason I wanted show up  the parent_id field from product.category to product.template Form view what I need to do?Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed field.

```
def _get_category(self):
    if not self.category_id or not self.category_id.parent_id: 
        self.category_parent_id = False
    else:
        self.category_parent_id = self.category_id.parent_id.id or False

category_parent_id = fields.Many2one('product.category',compute=_get_category)
```

Now you can just use category_parent_id directly in your form view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance.